# Problems installing laravel/openssl extensions

Tags: windows, laravel, composer-php

Trying to install Laravel for Windows. Downloaded the composer.phar file onto my desktop, and in command line ran: php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel learning-laravel-5.

Got this message:

Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: you must enable the openssl extension to download via https
Now trying to download from source...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate the according openssl-extension in your php.ini file.

**If you're using XAMPP:**
Find line `;extension=php_openssl.dll` in `xampp\php\php.ini` and remove the semicolon from the beginning of the line.

Hope that helps.